# Docker compose volume Permissions linux

Tags: linux, wordpress, docker, permissions, docker-compose

I try to run wordpress in a docker container my `docker-compose.yaml` file is:

```
version: "2"
services:
  my-wpdb:
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - "8081:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ChangeMeIfYouWant
  my-wp:
    image: wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - my-wpdb:mysql
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ChangeMeIfYouWant
```

When i build the docker structure the volume is mounted but belongs to root.

I tried to change that with:

```
my-wp:
  image: wordpress
  user: 1000:1000    # added
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  links:
    - my-wpdb:mysql
  environment:
    WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ChangeMeIfYouWant
```

Now I can edit files. But then the container doesn't serve the website anymore.

What is the right way to solve this permission issue?

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem or did you encounter further problems?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir) and [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user) reference, the `user` option sets the user id (and group id) of the process running in the container. If you set this to `1000:1000`, your webserver is not able to bind to port 80 any more. Binding to a port below 1024 requires root permissions. This means you should remove the added `user: 1000:1000` statement again.

To solve the permission issue with the shared volume, you need to change the ownership of the directory. Run `chown 1000:1000 /path/to/volume`. This can be executed inside the container or directly on the host system. The change is persistent and effective immediately (no container restarted required).

In general, I think the volume should be in a sub-directory, e.g.

```
  volumes:
    - ./public:/var/www/html
```

Make sure that the correct user owns `./public`. If you start the container and the directory does not exist, docker creates it for you. In this case, the directory is owned by `root` and you need to change ownership manually as explained above.

---

Alternatively, you can run the webserver as an unprivileged user (`user: 1000:1000`), let the server listen on port 8080 and change the routing to

```
 ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```

Comment: **Make sure that the correct user owns ./public. If you start the container and the directory does not exist, docker creates it for you. In this case, the directory is owned by root and you need to change ownership manually as explained above.**  

After days of looking up the root permissions issue I finally found the answer in your response. I had no idea the permission would be set as root if the folder isn't there before running build. This is crucial information that I feel should be explicitly stated in the docker docs; yet either it is not or I missed it somehow.

Comment: @sauerburger I have another problem. Docker (or Postgres Image, IDK) create the mounted directory for the first time (`docker-compose up --build`). but if I run the same command twice it gives me **permission denied**. I check the permission and it is: `systemd-coredump`. Why?

Comment: @mohammadjawadBarati It's difficult to debug this without more context, consider opening a separate question. However, the postgres image internally uses user `postgres` with uid 999. The user names mapped to user id's are most likely different on your host system, thus showing an unrelated user name as owner.

Comment: @sauerburger, this is [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66314764/how-can-i-guarantee-docker-host-volume-have-the-right-permission-after-multiple).

Comment: But you cant run a command in a failed to start container.

Answer (score 3):

answered in [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028878/permission-for-volumes-in-docker-compose/70168757#70168757)
use root user in your docker-compose to get full permission

EX:-

```
node-app:
    container_name: node-app
    image: node
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
      - ./node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
      - ./.env.docker:/home/node/app/.env
```

NOTE:- user: root => gives you a full permission of your volumne

Answer (score 0):

I was using Google Cloud shell and found that the following command enabled the correct permissions for me to use FTP file access with the WordPress docker container:

```
sudo chmod 644 -R wordpress-docker-compose
```

Comment: Never use 777, that is like asking to get robbed.

Comment: Yeah it was just an example. I should change it because I'm getting negative votes :-)