# Python - How to create a directory inside docker with permissions

Tags: python, docker

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  my_service:
    build: .
    container_name: my_container
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - ./script:/script
```

and the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:latest
COPY . .
CMD [ "python", "./script/test.py"]
```

`test.py`:

```
import os
os.makedirs('/script/my_new_folder_timestamp_here', 0o0777)
```

The `test.py` script creates a directory inside the container, with a name that is only known at run time (i.e with timestamp). That directory is created by default with root permissions and it can be accessed from host due to the created volume.
That means in order to access the folder from host, I can only do so as root.

My question is, how can I create a directory with python, inside the docker container, and be able to access it from host without root permission?

The objective is, in the dynamically created directory, there will be files that the user can load on a web app, using the [HTML Input Element](https://web.dev/read-files/#select). This is not possible if the directory or the files in it are root protected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker compose volume Permissions linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52917695/docker-compose-volume-permissions-linux)

Comment: I also discuss this topic in [Permissions best-practices when using docker exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69652433/permissions-best-practices-when-using-docker-exec).  Your Compose setup needs to specify a `user:` that has permission to write to the bind-mounted directory; it should be a different directory so your application isn't hidden by the mount.

Comment: @NoamYizraeli , @David I tried to set the `user: 1000:1000` like on  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52917695/docker-compose-volume-permissions-linux). Now I get `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` when I try to create a directory with the python script.

Comment: are you sure this is the user you have running in the container?